# Mono WebBrowser solution for Gtk# based project (on Mac OS)

Tags: macos, mono, gtk, browser

I have a Gtk# based project developed in Mono, target for Mac OS X. Now, I want to add a browser which is used just to display a static string with HTML format. However, I cannot find any solution. I know that Mono do support MonoMac.Webkit but it cannot be added into my Gtk application.

Do you guys have any experiences with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Webkit-sharp could be useful to you - I do not know however if it still works well. Some sample can be found [here](https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp/blob/master/samples/FunnyBrowser.cs).

On the other hand the Banshee team have their bindings to webkit, which are maintained and working well. You can find some source code [here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src/Core/Banshee.WebBrowser) (maybe just grabbing the [native library](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src/Core/Banshee.WebBrowser/libossifer/ossifer-web-view.c) and [GTK widget](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src/Core/Banshee.WebBrowser/Banshee.WebBrowser/OssiferWebView.cs) will do).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I found that it's quite difficult to integrate webkit-sharp in to Gtk application in Mac. However, since I only need to display a static HTML, so I used Gtk.Label with Pango Markup which can display some of the HTML tags with some minor modification.